# Comparing multiple struct fields in Go

Tags: unit-testing, struct, go

I was wondering if there is a generic way of unit testing the values of a rather large struct without having to write many if statements below each other. I know in Go we can use table-driven unit tests, but I have not yet found how we can implement this table-driven approach with structs.

My goal is to create a struct, do something with it, and unit test the new values of the struct. Does anybody know how I can achieve this with table-driven tests or if there's a better way to do it?

Comment: Do you want to check *all* fields, or only some of them?

Comment: All fields, if only have to check some of them I can just do them with a couple of if statements, but for all of them it just does not look like good practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to check all fields, just compare the structs:

```
type S struct {
    A int
    B float64
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(S{1, 3.14} == S{1, 3.14}) // Prints true.
}
```

Notice though that if your structs contain pointers, that may get tricky because they may point to two different but equal values. In that case, you can use [`reflect.DeepEqual`](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual):

```
type S2 struct {
    A int
    B *float64
}

func main() {
    var f1, f2 = 3.14, 3.14
    // Prints false because the pointers differ.
    fmt.Println(S2{1, &f1} == S2{1, &f2})
    // Prints true.
    fmt.Println(reflect.DeepEqual(S2{1, &f1}, S2{1, &f2}))
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/G24DbRDQE8.

Anything fancier than that will most probably require you to define your own equality methods.

Comment: Thanks, especially for the `reflect.DeepEqual`. I think I'll know how to manage it now, because I was a little worried about my pointers. Cheers